# Vertices Selection Problem

Tags: modeling

Whenever I try to select multiple vertices in edit mode using control-right click it doesn't work. What do I do? I have tried other keys but nothing has worked.

Comment: By default *Shift* is used to select multiple vertices.

Comment: Well I need it to connect the edges thought the vertices

Comment: it works for me, are you absolutely sure that the vertices are connected?
try moving around all intermediate vertices, there could be an isolated vertex (even if it _seems_ to be connected)